# The function $\phi\colon t \mapsto \int_{0}^{1}f(x,t)\, dx$ is Borel

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f\colon[0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. Functions $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ are integrable, functions $t \mapsto f(x,t)$ are continuous. I need to prove that the following function is Borel: $$\phi\colon t \mapsto \int_{0}^{1}f(x,t)\,dx.$$

I tried to use monotone class theorem for $E=\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\mid \phi^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}([0,1]) \} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. I need to show that $E=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. The only thing I managed to prove is that $E$ is an algebra. So, the idea seems wrong.

Please give me any ideas how to solve the problem. Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Did you mean to write $\phi: x \mapsto \int_{0}^{1}f(x,t)dt$?

Comment: @ Ben Grossmann No

Comment: Ok, but you meant to integrate with respect to $x$; now it makes sense

Comment: the notation in question and content isn't consistent is it dt or dx?

Comment: @user29418 it's dx (per the recent edit)

Answer (score 1):

The condition is so loose that it had me confused in many ways( it also made me question my understanding of measurability )
Your desired measurability ( of integrals) is already covered in (and also plays a part of ) the demonstration of Fubini's theorem. 
Moreover, as you know, the continuity property is still too much for only proving measurability.

If you want to **reproduce that theorem**, you have realized the right way to it, that is, to use the monotone class theorem( but in a more general setting). Let 
$$S:=\{ A \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])\otimes \mathcal{B}([0,1]) | f:= \mathbb{1}_{A} \text{ sasisties the respective }\phi \text{ is measurable}\}$$
then, this family $S$ is a Dynkin system, containing all product $1_{B\times C}$(where $B,C \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$).
From then you can prove your desired results with integrable positive functions.

Etc.


**Discussion**

- given your constraint, if we suppose further that $f$ is bounded **(1)**, you can even prove the continuity of $\phi$ by using dominated convergence theorem.
- The boundedness **(1)** perhaps can be relaxed, but more elaborate care should be put in.